# Gtmetrix / Specify image dimensions

Tags: html, css, wordpress, seo, gtmetrix

So I did a test on my website on `gtmetrix` and all the rows are green (>90%) only the first one which is `"Specify image dimensions"` is at 23%.

This is my html code:

```
<img height="300" width="300" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" srcset="http://www.my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/picture-300x300.jpg 300w, http://www.my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/picture-150x150.jpg 150w" alt="picture" class="alignleft margin-top-0 wp-post-image" src="http://www.my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/picture-300x300.jpg">
```

And this is the error I get:

```
http://www.my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/picture-300x300.jpg (Dimensions: 300 x 300)
http://www.my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/picture-150x150.jpg (Dimensions: 150 x 150)
```

It seems pretty strange because the width and height seem to be set, and also this picture was set automaticaly by wordpress as the default wordpress featured post. So this is not a code added by me, it was added by wordpress.

Does anybody know why I get this error on gtmetrix and how can I fix it? I am focused on SEO.